# Filtering Data by Department wise

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, filtering

I have a form with the name of Project Management, and here Coordinators(a type of user) will create projects and assign them to their own department sub-ordinates.

I wanted to filter the projects by the "Authorized By" filed, so that no coordinator will create projects for other departments. Also to prevent sub-ordinates from different departments to edit the projects, created by other departments.

here is the Fill,Get() query of main form.

```
SELECT PID, [Project Name], Priority, State, [Assigned to], [Submission Date], Est_Deadline, 
       [Authorized By], [TotalTasks Assigned], [Week num], [Project Progress]
FROM   Project Info]
where [Authorized By]=@pAuthorizedBy
```

in the parameter(@pAuthorizedBy) I will pass the ID of currently logged in Coordinator, so that all projects should be filtered department wise.

My problem is that, when fresh coordinators login, there is no project Authorized by him/her. so the program gives multiple errors.
is there any idea how to do it?

Comment: And the problem is not in the query but in your code that fails to handle this NULL condition. So start showing the first code that fails

Comment: Try IF EXISTS(your query)

Comment: here is the code in which the pIDTextbox fails to get any PID (Project ID) for the current logged in coordinator:

SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("select * from [Task Info] where PID=@pid", sqlcon);
sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@pid", int.Parse(pIDTextBox.Text));